# mybatis+oracle, program stuck on insertion

Tags: java, sql, oracle, optimization, mybatis

I'm writing a program with Java and myBatis. The program gets stuck with the following insertion with no error message. I checked Oracle and no data was inserted. I'm clueless why this is the case. Normally there would be some sort of error from either the sql or myBatis.

```
id type     number(10)
id_card_no  varchar2(50)
gene_info   varchar2(2000)
```

If more information is required, ask away. Thanks!

```
<insert id="addGenotype" parameterType="genotype" useGeneratedKeys="false" >
        insert into person_genotype (ID,ID_CARD_NO,GENE_INFO)
    <foreach collection="list" item="genotype" index="index" separator="UNION ALL">
        (select
        #{genotype.genotypeId},#{genotype.idCardNumber},#{genotype.geneInfo}
        FROM DUAL)
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Comment: Why do you use `foreach` and `SELECT FROM DUAL`?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Initially I used values instead of select from dual, comma instead of union all as separator, but I found out it would work with mysql but not oracle. I learned this way from another post.

Comment: the grammar would be insert into table(...) (select ... from dual) union all (select ... from dual)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there's another session to the database that inserted the row with the same primary key but has not committed yet. It is a rather common scenario to have `SQL*Plus` running with some uncommitted changes.

In Oracle if two concurrent transaction insert into the same table the row that conflicts on some unique key one of them would block until the other either commit or rollback.

One of the way to overcome this is to automatically generate identifiers for rows using a sequence. In this case every new record would get its own brand-new unique ID.